# Predict coordinates from input of coordinates

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-science-model

I'm a newbie at data science and I want to ask how can I predict a set of coordinates from a set of input coordinates? That is `(x1, y1) -> (x2, y2)`.

To give a bit of context, I am developing an eye tracker and I trying to map the coordinates of my eye to the coordinates of my gaze. My current implementation uses 2 linear regression models, 1 to predict x values and 1 to predict y values, but I am wondering if it is possible to directly predict both x and y values with 1 model.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using 2 different models for X and Y is not a good idea, since you are missing the correlation between the two. You are predicting new X coordinates based on old X coordinates and new Y coordinates based on old Y coordinates. What you want to do is predict new (x,y) based on old (x,y). So your intuition is correct that you should use one model and it is possible. What I would recommend is using a Kalman filter - you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) and an example implementation is found [here](https://pysource.com/2021/11/02/kalman-filter-predict-the-trajectory-of-an-object/).

Comment: Hi @Nemo_the_scientist, correct me if I'm wrong, but a Kalman filter estimates the current state based on the previous, for example, estimating the coordinates and/or velocity of a car based on the previous measured coordinates/velocity. In this case, I want to measure the gaze coordinates based on the eye coordinates. If I were to use a Kalman Filter, wouldn't I be using previously measured gaze coordinates to estimate the gaze coordinates? How would I then map the eye coordinates to the gaze coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. In this case, you can use a multi-output regression algorithm, instead of the two models. I think that [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/) tutorial might be of help.